# application not working after chrome update to version 66 but works in firefox and edge

Tags: angularjs, ajax, google-chrome, d3.js

[link to error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emnw4.png)2 days back google chrome automatically updated to version 66. Since then my site which was running perfectly stopped working in google chrome. But it works perfectly in firefox and edge. So i started debugging in google chrome, then i found that the problem is with ajax calls. So initially for the main page,  many ajax call will be hit. in that list of calls ,the last call executes the success part more than once. So when the susscess of response is executing for the second time it throws aw snap,page cannot be displayed error in chrome. Then i restricted the success call to once using some flag,then the main page was loading. But after submitting in left panel,the same ajax call will get hit, so now at this point i'm getting the same aw snap error. i'm using angularjs ajax. So please help me with this. when i debug i get below error message in console
[error message in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfslv.png)

As discussed in comment this function of d3.js code causes the application to crash.So when i commented this except this chart all other things are working

```html
var carbon = new Charts();
 var chart = d3.select(this.selector);
 var width = carbon.pixToVal(chart.style("width"));
 var height = carbon.pixToVal(chart.style("height"));
 /*var width=475;
 var height=133;*/
 /*var maxVal =100;*/
 var maxVal =d3.max(jsonData,function(d){return d.current;})+ 15;
 var length1=jsonData.length;
 
 var newWidthParts=newWidth/10;
 /*console.log(length1);
 console.log(newWidth);*/ 
 var newHeightParts=height/10;
 var conatinerRectHt=newHeightParts*6.5;
 /*var boxHeight=(newHeightParts*9-newHeightParts*2.5)/5;*/
 var margin={
   top: 15, left:15,right:15,bottom:20 
 }
 var availableWidth = width - margin.left - margin. right;

 var newWidth= availableWidth/length1;
 var availableHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 var HeightForTopLabel =15;
 var HeightForBottomLabel = 15;
 var HeightOfAbsValue = 15;
 var HeightForMidLabel = 15;
 var OuterRectHeight= availableHeight - (HeightForBottomLabel) - HeightForTopLabel; /*- HeightOfAbsValue;*/
/* var BottomTextYPosition = margin.top + HeightForTopLabel + OuterRectHeight + HeightForBottomLabel ;
*/ 
 var outerRectBottomYPosition = margin.top + HeightForTopLabel +OuterRectHeight;
 //outerRectTopYPosition + OuterRectHeight
 var outerRectTopYPosition = margin.top + HeightForTopLabel;
 var BottomTextYPosition = height - margin.bottom;
 var outerRectWidth = 50;
 var innerRectWidth =8;
 var outerRectDistFromLeft = newWidth/2 - outerRectWidth/2 + margin.left ;
 var innerRectDistFromLeft = newWidth/2 - innerRectWidth/2 + margin.left ;
 
 var creatSvg = chart.append("div").attr("class", "chartBox9")
 .style("position", "absolute")
 .style("height", "100%")
 .style("width", "100%")
 .append("svg").attr('id','defsGrad')
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height);
 
 d3.select("#defsGrad")
 .append("text").attr("x",availableWidth - 1.8*(margin.left + margin.right) )
 .attr("y",height-5)
 .attr("id","shareContritext")
 .text("% Room Revenue")
 .attr("font-size",10.5);

 
 
 d3.select("#defsGrad").append("defs").append("linearGradient").attr('id','grad1')
 .attr({'x1':'0%','y1':'100%','x2':'0%' ,'y2':'0%'}).append('stop')
 .attr('offset',"0%").style({'stop-color':'rgb(215,214,214)','stop-opacity':'0.7'});
 d3.select('#grad1').append('stop')
 .attr('offset',"100%").style({'stop-color':'rgb(249,249,249)','stop-opacity':'0.9'});
 
 
 
 
 svgContainer=creatSvg.selectAll('g')
 .data(jsonData).enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",function(d,i){
  var res = "translate(";
  var val = i*newWidth;
  return res+val+" 0)";
  });
 
 svgContainer.append("text")
   .attr("y", margin.top)
    .attr("font-size",fontsize)
   .text(function(d) {
    if( d.current == null){
     d3.select(this).attr("x",outerRectDistFromLeft + outerRectWidth/5 + 5);
     return "N/A";
    }else
     {
    var xposition =   outerRectDistFromLeft + (outerRectWidth/5+4);
       var nbr = d.current;
      // var decimals = (nbr!=Math.floor(nbr))?(nbr.toString()).split('.')[0].length:0;
       var decimals;
    
    if(nbr % 1 !== 0)
     {
     decimals = (nbr!=Math.floor(nbr))?(nbr.toString()).split('.')[0].length:0;
     }else
      {
      
        decimals = nbr.toString().length;
      
      }
   
       d3.select(this).attr("x",xposition-(decimals-1)*4);
  
    if(d.change==null)
    {
   d3.select(this).attr("x",outerRectDistFromLeft + outerRectWidth/5 + 5);
    }
   return d.current_prefix + d.current.toFixed(1) + d.current_suffix;}
   });
 
 var rectangle1 = svgContainer.append("rect")
 .attr("class","outerRect9")
   .attr("x", outerRectDistFromLeft)
   .attr("y",outerRectTopYPosition)
   .attr("width", outerRectWidth)
   .attr("height", OuterRectHeight)
   .attr("fill", "url(#grad1)");
 
 svgContainer.append("text")
   .attr("y", margin.top + HeightForTopLabel  -2 )
   .attr("fill",
    function(d){
     var colorChange="";
     if(d.change>=0.0)
      colorChange="#06C10C";
    
     else
      colorChange="#F7063A";
      return colorChange;
     }
   )
     .attr("font-size",fontsize)
    .text(function(d) {
    if( d.change == null){
     d3.select(this).attr("fill","black");
     d3.select(this).attr("x",outerRectDistFromLeft + outerRectWidth/5 + 7);
     return "N/A";
    }else{
         var pre ="";
       if(d.change>=0.0)
         pre="+";
     
       /*if(d.current!=null)
      {
        d3.select(this).attr("x",  outerRectDistFromLeft + outerRectWidth/5+3 );
      }*/
       
        var xposition = outerRectDistFromLeft + outerRectWidth/5;
    
    /* if(d.current =! null){
      d3.select(this).attr("x", xposition);
     }
     else
      {
      d3.select(this).attr("x", xposition);
      }*/
        
        d3.select(this).attr("x", xposition);
       
     return pre+d.change.toFixed(1)/*+d.change_suffix*/;}
   });
 var rectangle0=svgContainer.append('rect') .attr("x", innerRectDistFromLeft)
   .attr("y",outerRectTopYPosition).attr('width',8).attr('height',OuterRectHeight)
    .attr('fill','#BDBDB7').attr('opacity',0.5);
 
 
 var rectangle2=svgContainer.append('rect') .attr("x", innerRectDistFromLeft)
   .attr("y", function(d) {
   
    if(d.current == null){return (margin.top + HeightForTopLabel +OuterRectHeight);}
    else{ return (margin.top + HeightForTopLabel +OuterRectHeight)  - ((d.current/maxVal)*OuterRectHeight);}
    }).attr('width',8).attr('height',function(d) {
     if(d.current == null){
      return 0;
     }
     else{  return ((d.current/maxVal)*OuterRectHeight);}
    }).attr('fill',function(d,i){return d.color_code;});
 
 
 var data1 = d3.range(5)
 var c = d3.scale.ordinal()
     .domain(data1)
     .rangeBands([outerRectBottomYPosition + 1.5  ,outerRectTopYPosition ])
          
 

 var innerRect= svgContainer.selectAll('.inners')
   .data(data1)
   .enter()
    .append('rect').attr('class','inners')
     .attr('y',function(d) { return (c(d));/*return Math.round(c(d))*/ })
     .attr('x',innerRectDistFromLeft )
     .attr('width',8)     
     .attr('height',(OuterRectHeight/5) )/*+ (1.5*3)*/
          .style('stroke','#F6F6F6')
          .style('stroke-width','1.2')
          .style('fill', "none");
 

 svgContainer.append("text")
   .attr("x",function(d,i){
    var name =d.name;
    var lengthOfText = name.length;
    if(lengthOfText > 2){
     return outerRectDistFromLeft + outerRectWidth/3 - lengthOfText*2;
    }
    else {
     return outerRectDistFromLeft + outerRectWidth/3;
    }
   }  )
   .attr("y", BottomTextYPosition)
   .attr("font-size",fontsize)
   .text(function(d) {
     return d.name;
   })
   .on("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
    .on("mouseout", handleMouseOut);

    
    function handleMouseOver(d, i) { 
    
     creatSvg.append("rect").attr({
      id: "tooltipvaluebox",
      y: BottomTextYPosition,
      height: 20,
      fill:"#CACACE",
      
     })
     .attr("x",function(){
    var len = (d.fullName.length*10)+20;
    var val = newWidth*i;
    if((val+len)>width){
     var diff = (val+len) - width;
     val = val - (diff+5);
    }
    return val+8;  
   } )
     .attr("width",function(){
       var len = d.fullName.length;
       return (len*10)+20;
      });
     creatSvg.append("text").attr({
      id: "tooltipvalue",
      
      y: BottomTextYPosition+15
     })
     .attr("x",function(){
    var len = (d.fullName.length*10)+20;
    var val = newWidth*i;
    if((val+len)>width){
     var diff = (val+len) - width;
     val = val - (diff+5);
    }
    return val+8;  
   } )
     .text(function() {

      return d.fullName ;
     })
     .attr('fill','black')
     .style("font-family", "roboto");
    };
    function handleMouseOut(d, i) {
     
     d3.select("#tooltipvaluebox").remove();
     d3.select("#tooltipvalue").remove();
    };
```

Comment: Could you please share the error massage?

Comment: i've edited my post and added the link of my error message

Comment: @anjaliarasu you should be checking the browser console for errors (`F12` key, or `Ctrl + Shift + J`)

Comment: yeah i checked it. But after the second ajax request the browser gets disconnected from the application. no error is there in the console

Comment: but when i debug, sometimes i get an error message i'm adding that in post now

Comment: @anjaliarasu nobody can help you, unless you post an error or your code here (_[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50018263/edit) your question_). Also which ajax? `$http` or `$.ajax`?

Comment: i have posted the error link again in the post.please check it. and the ajax is $http

Comment: the error points to a piece of code that causes the crash, you can check that. Also are you using `Object.keys()` anywhere in that region of code? If it takes an `undefined` or `null` value it will show that error. It could also be an error within `XMLHttpRequest`, so once again review your code as it might not be clear where it's coming from

Comment: i have debugged more and found the issue is with a particular d3.js code which is breaking the whole function. but that part of code is not breaking always it breaks for the second time call only. so can you help with this. i'm posting the code of my d3.js function. what i doubt is the cors update of chrome version 66. is d3 has anything to do with that?

Comment: there is no Object.keys() in any part of my code

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Version 66 for Windows seems to have a critical Bug in the DEV Engine. I think it's related to the meltdown hotfix in version 66. Its already fixed in Dev Channel V 68.x